# twitter bootstrap resize the text size on phone screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am new to twitter bootstrap. I am hiding some `<tr>` on phone screen with the help of `class="hidden-phone"`

But I want to resize the shown text to fit to the screen

How can I resize the text in spans like below on phone screen?

```
<span>test test test test test</span>
```

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: Are you using responsive bootstrap (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)?

CSS-Solution: You could use media queries to check if the user's device is a smartphone or tablet and then apply a new size to your span elements.

Comment: I want to make 'fbnt-size:8px' on phone screen. how do I add this property to ".visible-phone" ?

Comment: @ayilmaz you don't have to put a `.visible-phone` class, you just have to make the `.hidden-phone` class visible for mobile viewport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you work with mobile viewport in twitter bootstrap (or any other solution for that matter)

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
        body {
          font-size: 11px;
        }

        .hidden-phone {
           display: block;
        }
    }
```