# bigger font on mobile devices using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

I want to make bigger fonts for my content for my app, where CSS is based on twitter bootstrap 3. I've already tried solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454594/twitter-bootstrap-resize-the-text-size-on-phone-screen) but it gets overriden by bootstrap itself, I tried:

```
@media (max-width: 600px)
html {
  font-size: 130%; // strikethrough in chrome = inactive style
}
```

This is how I'm loading my CSSes (bootstrap files are fetched from bower):

```
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What can I do to make fonts bigger for max-width devices?

---

edit: adding `!important` doesn't change anything. I can see that bootstrap is overwriting font from following CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Where are you putting that CSS? Is it definitely loading after the default bootstrap files?

Comment: You know you're missing braces on the media query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work but be sure to include the code *after* the bootstrap CSS

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
  html {
    font-size: 130% !important; // strikethrough in chrome = inactive style
  }
}
```

If it's being overwritten by `body` then use:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
  body {
    font-size: 130% !important; // strikethrough in chrome = inactive style
  }
}
```

Comment: You are missing some braces here.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz have a look at revised answer

Comment: @DavidG Have corrected my code, you're right, probably better to show it properly and it might have been the issue anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font on the html **and** the body and load your css after the bootstrap CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    html, body {
      font-size: 130%; // strikethrough in chrome = inactive style
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing braces around your media query. Without these braces, the media query won't actually apply to anything subsequent.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) 
{
    html {
        font-size: 130%; // strikethrough in chrome = inactive style
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing braces around your media query, it should read

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
html {
 font-size: 130%; // strikethrough in chrome = inactive style
 }
}
```